# "Not enough storage is avaliable to process this command"

Tags: java, java-native-interface

When my program runs, following error was taken:

```
Excepiton in theard "AWT -EventQueue -1" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: program.dll: Not enough storage is avaliable to process this command

[java] at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load<Native Method>
[java] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0<ClassLoader.java:1751>
[java] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary<ClassLoader.java:1647>
[java] at java.lang.Runtime.load0<Runtime.java:769>
[java] at java.lang.System.load<System.java:968>
```

How can I solve this problem...

Thanks for help..

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978735.aspx 
Tried to load the native library separately - in a small test app perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

This is a message from Windows indicating that you have run out of memory - not your Java heap, but the machine heap.  How does the memory look on your machine while you are trying to run your app?

Comment: ın my program three java.exe run, these are:

java.exe 15.288 K
java.exe 180.416 K
java.exe 308.084 K

Comment: are there any non-java of the processes on your system?  this error is complaining about total system memory.

Comment: Process:39
Physical Memory(k)
total 2087084
avaliable 941976
System Cache 1227552
Kernel Memory(k)
total 200632
paged 174960
nonpaged 25672

total 
handles 17109
Threads 525
Process 40

Commit Charge(k)
total 1008388
limit 4025608
peak 1595908

Answer (score 1):

When native libraries are loaded into the JVM they are mapped into the JVMs address space and any calls they make to allocate memory do so in that address space - therefore in a 32bit world you've got a maximum of 4GB to play with.

Competing for this 4GB is the JVM and it's heap (although I believe there are limits to the heap size other than the address space that a JVM specific).

Anyway, from your comments on @akf's answer it looks like there's plenty of memory.

I'd also consider that the term 'storage' could refer to more than just memory.

From the Javadoc on `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`:

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine
>   cannot find an appropriate
>   native-language definition of a method
>   declared native.

Please explain/confirm:

- is `program.dll` on your `java.library.path` and are you successfully calling other methods on it.
- what is `program.dll` and what are you using it for.

Comment: program.dll is 93 MB , that is so big. when i write application for using program.dll,it runs. But when i integrate an other big application, it does not work.How can i solve this problem.

Comment: What do the memory stats look like for the application that works?  Are you using the same JVM for both?

Comment: yes i am using samr JVM for both.
 when i run application.jar that works, CPU:24, Mem Usage:14 124 K

Comment: can i solve this problem by creating new thread in other big application when loading program.dll

Comment: That's weird but if it works it works, cool.  Wonder if the DLL does something with thread local, that's the only thing I can think of that might cause that.